# Twig form Template : Unable to access a PersistentCollection property from "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView". Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm building a form for an entity called "Fournisseur" who contain a `CollectionType` field for the associated Entity "Contact". I properly create the form view who contain all "contact" entries and their property if exists.

But I have a trouble when I'm trying to apply a form theme on this specific `CollectionType` field: I cannot access to some property and I get this message:

"Neither the property `prenom` nor one of the methods `prenom()`, `getprenom()`/`isprenom()`/`hasprenom()` or `__call()` exist and have public access in class `Symfony\Component\Form\FormView`.

I realized that I only get this trouble on fields which the name doesn't exist in the `Fournisseur` Entity. For example, I can access the `nom` and `email` property in `Contact` Entity because `Fournisseur` entity got the same property and ->createView seems to got this property. But I cannot access other property of "Contact".

You'll see my code below.

Thank you so much for your help.
Florian.

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/fournisseur/ajax/edit/{id}", name="admin_fournisseur_ajax_edit", condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()")
 */

public function admin_transporteur_ajax_edit(AtmosFournisseur $fournisseur, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(FournisseurType::class, $fournisseur, array(
       'action' => "/admin/fournisseur/ajax/edit/".$fournisseur->getId()
    ))
    ->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $manager->persist($fournisseur);
        $manager->flush();
        return new Response('success');
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render('admin/fournisseur/partials/_edit.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'fournisseur'=>$fournisseur,
        ]); 
    }
}
```

**FournisseurType Form**

```
    class FournisseurType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom du fournisseur'
            ])
            ->add('code', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Code COGILOG du fournisseur'
            ])
            ->add('adrNum', NumberType::class, [
                'label' => 'N° Voie'
            ])
            ->add('adrVoie', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Code COGILOG du fournisseur'
            ])
            ->add('adrComp1', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Complément d\'adresse 1'
            ])
            ->add('adrComp2', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Complément d\'adresse 2'
            ])
            ->add('adrCP', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Code Postal'
            ])
            ->add('adrCedex', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Cedex'
            ])
            ->add('adrPays', CountryType::class, [
                'label' => 'Pays',
                'choice_translation_locale' => 'fr'
            ])
            ->add('telephone', TelType::class, [
                'label' => 'N° de téléphone'
            ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => 'Adresse e-mail'
            ])
            ->add('adrVille', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Ville'
            ])
            ->add('contacts', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => AtmosFournisseurContactType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => AtmosFournisseur::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Twig template**

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% form_theme form _self %}

    <div class="row bg-light">
        <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Editer le fournisseur</h4></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">{{ form_row(form.nom) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">{{ form_row(form.code) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">{{ form_row(form.adrNum) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">{{ form_row(form.adrVoie) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">{{ form_row(form.adrComp1) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">{{ form_row(form.adrComp2) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">{{ form_row(form.adrCP) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">{{ form_row(form.adrCedex) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">{{ form_row(form.adrVille) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">{{ form_row(form.adrPays) }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">{{ form_row(form.contacts) }}</div>
    </div>

    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enregistrer le formulaire</button>

{{ form_end(form) }}



{% block _fournisseur_contacts_widget %}
    <div style="background:red;">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block _fournisseur_contacts_entry_row %}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endblock %}


{% block _fournisseur_contacts_entry_widget %}
    {{ dump(form)}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_row(form.nom) }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_row(form.prenom) }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_row(form.fonction) }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_row(form.telephone) }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_row(form.email) }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**AtmosFournisseurContactType Code**

```
class AtmosFournisseurContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom'
            ])
            ->add('prenom', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Prénom'
            ])
            ->add('telephone', TelType::class, [
                'label' => 'N° de téléphone'
            ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => 'E-mail'
            ])
            ->add('fonction', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Fonction'
            ])
        ;
    }
```

**FormView in _fournisseur_contacts_entry_widget **

```
`FormView^ {#739 ▼
  +vars: array:30 [▶]
  +parent: null
  +children: array:14 [▼
    "nom" => FormView^ {#1036 ▶}
    "code" => FormView^ {#1032 ▶}
    "adrNum" => FormView^ {#894 ▶}
    "adrVoie" => FormView^ {#871 ▶}
    "adrComp1" => FormView^ {#843 ▶}
    "adrComp2" => FormView^ {#807 ▶}
    "adrCP" => FormView^ {#783 ▶}
    "adrCedex" => FormView^ {#437 ▶}
    "adrPays" => FormView^ {#1115 ▶}
    "telephone" => FormView^ {#1520 ▶}
    "email" => FormView^ {#1522 ▶}
    "adrVille" => FormView^ {#1524 ▶}
    "contacts" => FormView^ {#1526 ▼
      +vars: array:33 [▶]
      +parent: FormView^ {#739}
      +children: array:2 [▶]
      -rendered: true
      -methodRendered: false
    }
    "_token" => FormView^ {#1569 ▶}
  ]
  -rendered: true
  -methodRendered: true
`
```

**_fournisseur_contacts_widget dum results **

```
 FormView^ {#1526 ▼
  +vars: array:33 [▶]
  +parent: FormView^ {#739 ▶}
  +children: array:2 [▼
    0 => FormView^ {#1542 ▶}
    1 => FormView^ {#1544 ▶}
  ]
  -rendered: false
  -methodRendered: false
}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you add the code of `AtmosFournisseurContactType` in your question please.

Comment: @qdequippe I've added it on the post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: thx, could you add also the `dump(form)` in `{% block _fournisseur_contacts_entry_widget %}`

Comment: @qdequipe I've added the dump results. I realized that give me the main form "Fournisseur". I don't understand why b/c I'm supposed to be in fournisseur_contacts field. Thx.

Comment: did you try just `{%block _contracts_entry_widget %}`?